# Class cast exception passing interface to constructor mockito junit

Tags: java, junit, interface, mockito

How do I avoid class cast exception with following example:

```
interface AbstractMapper {
 mapTo();
 mapFrom();
}

class TestClass {
  @Mock
  AbstractMapper instanceMapperClass;

  Class testClass;

  @Setup
  public void setup(){
    instanceMapperClass = (InstanceMapper) instanceMapperClass;
    testClass = new Class(instanceMapperClass);
  }
}
```

Where InstanceMapper implements AbstractMapper.

So abstractMapper.mapTo(abstractMapper) takes interface as parameter. The error returned from mockito is the generic class cast exception.

One option is to make constructor of the Class under test to take AbstractMapper instead of the InstanceMapper however this doesn't seem to be good java practice as it should only accept InstanceMapper. What is the best way to go about this.

Comment: Change the field declaration to `@Mock InstanceMapper instanceMapperClass`?

Comment: how does  `InstanceMapper` relates to `AbstractMapper`?

Comment: Andy - that would then lead to me having to cast it back to AbstractMapper when writing the Mockito.when(listmapper.mapTo((AbstractMapper) instanceMapper).

Comment: Rajith I've updated this - it implements AbstractMapper

Answer (score 0):

you can't do cast instanceMapperClass to InstanceMapper as instanceMapperClass  it's mocked proxy and as result you get classCastException. If you need instanceMapperClass be a InstanceMapper do this :

```
instanceMapperClass = mock(InstanceMapper.class)
```

in this case instanceMapperClass created as InstanceMapper with proxy.